# How to statistics sales, city, customer of goods use oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a oracle view, and include the sale of goods details. It like this:

### OrderId   OrderDetailId   GoodsId   GoodsName   UnitName   SalesQty   Price   CustomerName   Country   City

```
200138   ddd0a3b42adb   770   A   bag      5    18.00   AAAA    USA     NewYork  
223448   70ca7ceb41c7   193   D   bottle   10   10.00   BBB     USA     NewYork  
200118   ab472857573e   1286  F   cup      8    50.00   CCC     China   Beijing    
244028   230a43920667   770   A   bag      20   18.00   CCC     China   Beijing    
251118   118fc2b3839b   5929  C   box      40   6.00    DDDD    Japan   Tokyo    
200000   abd0a3b42ddd   770   A   bag      15   18.00   AAAA    USA     NewYork  
111118   11111113839b   5929  C   box      40   6.00    FFFF    Japan   Tokyo
```

And I want a SQL statement statistics sales, the number of cities, the number of customers of each goods. The result should be like this:

### GoodsId   GoodsName   SalesQty(UnitName)   CityQty  CustomerQty

```
GoodsId   GoodsName   SalesQty(UnitName)   CityQty  CustomerQty
770       A           40(bag)              2        2
193       D           10(bottle)           1        1
1286      F           8(cup)               1        1
5929      C           80(box)              1        2
```

How to write sql statistical statement? Thanks!

Comment: I believe that `CityQty` in the last row should be one and `CustomerQty` should be two.

Comment: @RadimBača Yes, you are right, I got it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `GROUP BY`

```
select GoodsId, GoodsName, UnitName, 
       sum(SalesQty) SalesQty, 
       count(distinct City) CityQty,
       count(distinct CustomerName) CustomerQty
from goods_view
group by GoodsId, GoodsName, UnitName
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f96bfa9eabfa7cf462bb69e33972fe89)

Comment: Good, I don't know use distinct in count. Your reply is correct, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `cube`, to include also sub&grand totals of quantities :

```
select GoodsId, GoodsName||'('||UnitName||')' GoodsName,
   sum(SalesQty) SalesQty, count(distinct City) CityQty, count(distinct CustomerName) CustomerQty
  from v_goods
 group by cube(GoodsId, GoodsName||'('||UnitName||')')
 order by GoodsId,GoodsName||'('||UnitName||')';
```

Comment: @Net205 you're welcome, i thought you need totals in your statistics. By the way, i've edited the answer to include unitnames in parathesis, recommend you try in your db.